# Excel VBA SQL Select Returns NULL for Strings in Mixed Strings/Numbers Column

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using a simple SQL query in Excel VBA on an Excel table.
One of my SELECT columns has both blank cells, numeric values and strings.
Only the Numeric values are properly returned, while the String values are returned as NULL.
I tried CStr(mixed-column) to no avail.
If I remove all numeric values from the column - all works fine - strings are being returned.
Any suggestions?

In the below code, the first field is the mixed-values field (RD.[Broker Reference Number]).

```vb
Sub testGetIntoArray()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim strSQL As String


    strSQL = "SELECT  CStr(RD.[Broker Reference Number]), RD.[Type], RD.[Currency], RD.[Total Due]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Risks Details$B10:AG2207] as RD"
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (RD.[Risk Details Number] = 170083001)"

    result = LoadSQLQueryIntoArray(strSQL, arr)

    Debug.Print (arr(0, 0))
End Sub



Function LoadSQLQueryIntoArray(ByVal strSQL As String, ByRef arr() As Variant) As Long
'Load result of SQL Query string into array
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
LoadSQLQueryIntoArray = 0

If InProduction Then On Error GoTo FailesSub

ConnectDB
rs.Open strSQL, ConnDB
If Not (rs.EOF) Then
    arr = rs.GetRows

    LoadSQLQueryIntoArray = UBound(arr, 2) + 1
End If
rs.Close

CloseSub:
Set rs = Nothing
DisconnectDB
Exit Function
FailesSub:
    MsgBox "Failed reading DB table: " & strTable & ".", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Database Error"
    GoTo CloseSub
End Function
```

Comment: Your `LoadSQLQueryIntoArray` returns Long (rows count). What's the connection with your question?

Comment: @JohnyL - It has nothing to do with my question. The issue is the dataset returned from the DB (Excel table) - not the funtion return type. Put this in a SUB to experience the same issue...

Comment: One field must be in the same data format. There is a tendency to determine the format of the field by the first few dozen data.

Comment: @Dy Lee - Well, this "tendency" fails my query... Anyway to avoid it in the query itself?

Comment: Look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/)

Comment: @JohnyL - thanks! however, this setting applies to all tables, not just a single column...